# Is it correct to replace a general schema.org item with a more specific sub item

Tags: microdata

I've recently been looking at the schema vocab for describing the layout of a webpage.

The easiest and most obvious item to implement is the WebPage tag.

If you're just assigning http://schema.org/WebPage to a page, then adding it to the body tag makes sense.

However suppose your page is a search results page or a profile page, there are two relevent WebPage sub types for those cases:

- http://schema.org/ProfilePage
- http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage

My instinct is that you'd replace WebPage with the correct sub category in the body tag, however often when I come across implementations of this, for example the following [theme](http://wpsites.net/wordpress-themes/adding-custom-schema-in-genesis-for-your-specific-niche/), it recommends putting the sub categories separately inside the webpage object.

Is this correct, or should you replace a more general item with a more specific one when you can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If your web page is a search results page, simply use [`SearchResultsPage`](http://schema.org/SearchResultsPage) **instead** of [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage).

  It’s a hierarchy. Each child inherits from all its ancestors. So a `SearchResultsPage` is a more specific `WebPage`, which is a more specific `CreativeWork`, which is a more specific `Thing`.

  Always go with the most specific type that applies to your case. On a type’s page, the more specific types are linked in the bottom under the "More specific Types" section.
- If your web page is both, a search results page *and* a profile page (which is rather unlikely … even if the profile shows all the author’s posts, it’s not really a search, is it?), use **both** types, `ProfilePage` and `SearchResultsPage`.

---

> putting the sub categories separately inside the webpage object

It depends on how exactly the "sub" items are specified.
If they are added with a property, they are related to the parent item (and the property specifies the kind of relationship).
If they are not added with a property, they have no relation, each item is on its own.

Comment: Cheers, I was reasonably sure it was a hierarchy but there's enough conflicting information out there that it's easy to get a little bit lost.